# Ionic 3 event emitter performance

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app, angular-event-emitter

I'm working in a large Ionic app with about 25k lines and a lot of components, the app has performance issues and memory leaks.

I was thinking that the problem could be in the intensive use of event emitter class, but I need some data related to it cause I was searching about event emitter and Ionic/Angular apps performance issues but I can't find anything.

An example of use the event emitter I found in the app is:

The dashboard component emit and event when the tasks list is full loaded from the backend service, and this event is caught in the Header and Footer component to enable some buttons.

My question: is it a bad idea to use event emitter for component communication in Ionic/Angular?

And: could the event emitter class have performance issues if is used in incorrect way?

Answer (score 0):

We are using event emitters in a project more than 120k line and we haven't experienced performance issues yet. **So I think this is not the problem.**

In our experiences the biggest factor of performance issues could be the unhandled Observables and bad usage of lifecycle events.